# Powershell Logic in operators

Tags: powershell, logic

I have a script which pulls variables and compares them against each other.
Most of them works perfectly fine, but there seems to be a problem with this particular variable.

```
 secedit /export /cfg C:\secedit.txt
 $var = import-csv C:\secedit.txt
 $holding = $var[4] -match "(\d+)"
 $a=$matches[1]
```

Assuming `$var[4]` is

```
Maximum Password Length = 100

$a will be 100
```

But when I do a comparision with

`if($a -gt 50){"true"}`
My result will be `false`.

After troubleshooting, only if the value is 1, then it will be recognised as true.

However, doing mathematical operations such as `$a/5 $a-1` all willl result in correct values with 20 and 99 respectivly.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `$a.GetType()` you will see that `$a` is `System.String`. If you use the string to do some arithmetic, it will be *implicitly* get castet to a number. However, if you compare the string using `-gt`, you have to *explicit* cast the value:

```
 secedit /export /cfg C:\secedit.txt
 $var = import-csv C:\secedit.txt
 $holding = $var[4] -match "(\d+)"
 $a=[int]$matches[1]
```

Comment: Figured this out after trying to add 1 and it became 1001 ! thanks alot! can only accept answer after 6 minutes though!